# jpa concurrency CMT exception handling

Tags: jpa, concurrency

I use EntityManager to save/update my entities in database and Hibernate as jpa provider. My transactions are handled by container.

The problem: I need to add an entity that might have been already stored in database, so an exception will be thrown. In this case I need to repeat insertion but with another value. But as long as an exception is thrown the session has gone bad and I need to create a new session and rollback the transaction. How can I do this when I'm using CMT? Or if there is another way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `TransactionAttribute(REQUIRES_NEW)` for your persistence method. If the bean invoking your method will catch an exception, it might do some changes and invoke the method once again.
This will rollback just the persistence-method transaction - not the invoking bean one.

However, remember that if your Use Case doesn't require you to do `EntityManager#persistence(-)`, you might be interested in `EntityManager#merge(-)` operation. It will **persist** the entity if it doesn't already exist or **update** it if it already exists (the existence is checked based on the PK).

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use EntityManager#find(Class, PK) to check for an already persisted entity. A null result means there's no such entity ( ----> persist(.) ), otherwise you update with the merge(.) method.

Comment: Yes, I know that. I wanted to create a system, that was described on this site in one question (can't find the link now): the database is to ensure that added values are unique using unique constraint. I must emphasize here that we must handle concurrent requests and I tried to avoid synchronizing my insert method. Using proper exception handling we can ensure that every time a unique value added. This is what I wanted in the first place.